# Gatsby/Hugo/MKDocs for markdown docs inside React SPA with dynamic functionality

Tags: reactjs, markdown, gatsby, hugo, mkdocs

I need to build an website that has dynamic functionalities - having a search and posting as well as receiving data from a RESTful API. We have decided to go with with React.js for the front end. We also need documentation in the app which will be written and stored in Markdown.

Do you have any advice whether to go with Hugo Gatsby or MK Docs? Hugo and MKDocs seem to have more themes available but I am not sure how easy it is to blend either of these two with React? I know Gatsby is React based but there seems to be less themes available.

If anyone has had a similar choice to make could you share your experience? And perhaps some links on articles or repositories that are open source of course which I could use to get some idea how to structure such a project? Especially examples on blending Hugo and MKDocs with react SPA ? I have not found any working ones so far. Any tips on what to focus on when setting up and making the decision would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: If you decided to use React for the front-end choosing Gatsby is pretty obvious. And their official docs have tutorials, plenty of examples, and boilerplates.